# How can we add 'Arabic' Text in jsPDF?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, jspdf

I am using jsPDF and i am stuck at putting the Arabic text in the file, if i put the arabic string its prints very odd english characters.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'حيدر'); //Arabic Text
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now, jspdf doesnot support unicode characters. If you are okay with lower resolution of the pdf, you can try using html2canvas library along with jspdf, which is quiet easier approach.